# Связь между ViewModel в паттерне MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте. Хотелось бы вашего совета. Только начинаю использовать MVVM. Допустим, есть окно MainWindow, в котором находится статус-бар и некоторая индикацию. В это окно помещается, к примеру, UserControl, где находится некоторое меню.
По логике вещей, у окна и usercontrol'a свои ViewModel. Вопрос: как тогда обратиться из одной viewmodel в другую? Например, после выполнения некоторого действия из меню, мне нужно изменить текст в статус-баре.
Конечно передавать объект одной viewmodel'и в другой нельзя. Нарушение инкапсуляции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В принципе, ничего страшного нету в том, чтобы одна VM знала о другой. Например, корневая VM обычно имеет ссылки на вложенные VM, и образует таким образом дерево.

С другой стороны, для сценария, который вы описываете, сообщение проходит из меню к статус-бару, должно работать не так. Для развязки точки, где генерируется событие, и точки где происходит реакция на него, используются *команды*. Я бы воспользовался такой архитектурой:

1. Пункт меню привязан к команде (`RoutedUICommand`). Например, [одной из ApplicationCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), или вы можете определить свою команду тоже¹.
2. Вам нужно будет зарегистрировать обработчики для команд при помощи [`CommandBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), глобально через [`CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.registerclasscommandbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) или локально через XAML (`<Window.CommandBindings>`).
3. Таким образом, VM, которая зарегистрировала обработчик команды, получит управление при выборе этой команды в меню.
4. Если результат выполнения устанавливает статус, VM, которая выполняет команду, должна знать кому сообщить об изменении статуса. Поскольку статус один на приложение, вы можете сделать его глобально доступным (VM-синглтон или публичное свойство корневой VM), а можете и развязать эту зависимость при помощи ещё одной команды.

Заметьте, что есть более прямой путь работы с командами, когда вы просто определяете класс, имплементирующий интерфейс `ICommand` (`CanExecute` + `Execute` + `CanExecuteChanged`). Это скорее всего не то, что вам надо, потому что такую команду сложнее «отвязать»: вы должны будете как-то передать экземпляр команды в меню. Для случая `RoutedUICommand` меню знает только *какую* команду оно хочет выполнить, а подсоединение исполнителя к команде происходит отдельно и независимо.

---

¹ Например, так:

```
static class ApplicationExtendedCommands
{
    public static ApplicationExtendedCommands Kaboom =
            new RoutedUICommand() { Text = "Destroy the planet" };
    public static ApplicationExtendedCommands About =
            new RoutedUICommand() { Text = "About application" };
}
```

Comment: Пример с RoutedUICommand мне знаком, но тут мы жестко фиксируем сообщение, а хочется в статус-бар отправлять любой текст. Да и я уже привык использовать свои системы команд (асинхронные и так далее) Тут конечно корневая VM выручает, но тогда появляется проблема: как вызвать из дочерней VM функцию корневой VM? В одной из программ видел реализацию через статическую, глобальную систему команд. То есть в одном месте определяем все команды. В каком-то смысле удобно, но с архитектурной точки зрения не очень.

Comment: Я в таких случаях просто делал события в дочерних VM. Далее в главной VM подписывался на них. Сгенерировали событие в дочернем VM -> запустился обработчик в главной VM.

Comment: @SergeyHoroshev: Нет, почему же? Текст не фиксирован. `Text` в `RoutedUICommand` — это не текст, который появится в статус-баре, это текст пункта меню.

Comment: @SergeyHoroshev: Если у вас есть свои команды, тогда сделайте просто свою кастомную команду, всё ещё проще.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @SergeyHoroshev: Пожалуйста!